# Infopath error while creating dataconnection

Tags: infopath2010

I created a SOAP webservice to use in infopath form and added the method which returns a data table as return type. When i try to add the dataconnection the method it gives me an error stating that "The selecetd XML document can not be used a data connection source because it includes inline XDR schemas".
 Here is the webmethod i wrote. it works well run it in the browser.

```
[WebMethod]
public DataTable GetApplications()
{
    DataTable dt;


        using (SPSite mysite = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Web.Url))
        {
            using (SPWeb myweb = mysite.OpenWeb())
            {

                SPSiteDataQuery query = new SPSiteDataQuery();
                query.Lists = "<Lists ServerTemplate=\"115\" />";
                query.ViewFields = "<FieldRef Name=\"Applicant File Number\" Nullable=\"TRUE\" Type=\"Text\" />" +
                                  "<FieldRef Name=\"Application Category \" Nullable=\"TRUE\" Type=\"Text\"/>" +
                                  "<FieldRef Name=\"Application Type  \" Nullable=\"TRUE\" Type=\"Text\"/>" +
                                 "<FieldRef Name=\"Submission ID  \" Nullable=\"TRUE\" Type=\"Text\"/>";
                query.Query = "<OrderBy>" +
                                "<FieldRef Name=\"Submission ID\" />" +
                            "</OrderBy>";
                query.Webs = "<Webs Scope=\"SiteCollection\" />";
                dt= myweb.GetSiteData(query);
                dt.TableName = "myApplications";
                return dt;
            }
        }        

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added the data table to a dataset and returned the dataset to infopath form through dataconnection. It worked well.